# Where to put servlet files in cpanel

Tags: mysql, servlets, jdbc, code-signing

I made a servlet that reads values from a database hosted on my site. It worked in Eclipse, but now how do I put it on my site so that people can access it?

Comment: You have to make a distributable war file of your servlet application and deploy it to your hosting server.

Comment: @PiyasDe After I make it, where do I put the file? In the root folder of the file system? or in the same folder as the html page?

Comment: If you are using tomcat then deployment directory will be <<Tomcat Installation Directory>>/webapps.  But if you are using cpanel - here is an useful link - http://www.jvmhost.com/articles/web-application-war-setup-shared-hosting-server